# Taxonomy Parent not showing up in address bar

Tags: templates, url-rewriting

I created a custom taxonomy successfully and assigned the custom post type as well. It is a hierarchical taxonomy and I added  terms in the back in a hierarchical way.

I added for instance main Category  "MAIN" and sub category  "Sub Cat". Now, when I go to look at  "Sub cat"  in the from end, I get   `/mysite.com/THE-CHOSEN-SLUG/sub-cat`    instead of `/mysite.com/THE-CHOSEN-SLUG/main/sub-cat`

What am I missing? I have worked with  CPT and custom taxonomies for a while already and am very versed in wordpress. Anything changed lately?

Comment: I found an answer within 10 minutes of posting this :). 

Just add  'hierarchical' => true   in the rewrite=>array()  of the taxonomy  as  follows: 

`register_taxonomy( 'BLABLABLABIG-TAXONOMY', 'talalalala', array( 'hierarchical' => true,. . . . . . . . . .  'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'categories','hierarchical' => true ))`

Then Go  back in the Permalink settings and save them to flush the  rewrite  rules and voila!

Comment: Then please add it as _answer_, not as comment. Thanks.

Comment: I have to wait for  8 hours because apparently new users is what they have to do :). Patience  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer within 10 minutes of posting this. :) Just add `'hierarchical' => true` in the `rewrite=>array()` of the taxonomy as follows:

```
$args = array( 
    ...
    'hierarchical'  => true,
    'rewrite'       => array( 
        'slug'          => 'THE-CHOSEN-SLUG',
        'hierarchical'  => true,
    ),
);
register_taxonomy( 'my-custom-taxonomy', array( 'page', 'my-custom-post-type' ), $args );
```

Then flush the rewrite rules by going to the Permalink settings and saving them, and voila!